# Equivalent of utf8_general_ci in Postgres/ICU?

Tags: postgresql, collation, international-components-unicode

In MySQL there is a collation `utf8_general_ci` which provides case-insensitive comparisons in a variety of languages. For example, these are all `1` (true):

```sql
SELECT 'ı' = 'I' SOLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
SELECT 'i' = 'I' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
SELECT 'ä' = 'Ä' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Can I define a similar collation using PostgreSQL's ICU?

I tried

```sql
CREATE COLLATION "undefined_ci_nondet_old" (
  PROVIDER = 'icu',
  LOCALE = "@colStrength=secondary",
  DETERMINISTIC = false
);
```

But that doesn't seem to include the Turkish I/ı conversion:

```sql
SELECT 'ı' = 'I' COLLATE undefined_ci_nondet_old; -- false
```

Comment: Will you be using the collation with a query? Or is this something you want to set at the database level?

Comment: you check the post and especoally the comment https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/225570/190821  maaybe this helps

Comment: @matigo Probably query-time, but either is fine.

Answer (score 3):

[The dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) is a special case. It's processed by the ICU collation service with rules that depend on the language.

If the locale refered to the Turkish or Azerbaijani languages, it would produce the result that speakers of these languages might expect (that is, `i` and `ı` are two different letters with `İ` and `I` being their respective uppercase counterparts; cross-comparisons return false). Otherwise the result is normally that `i` is the lowercase version of `I`, whereas `ı` is not.

```
postgres=# CREATE COLLATION "undefined_ci_nondet_old" (
  PROVIDER = 'icu',
  LOCALE = 'tr@colStrength=secondary',
  DETERMINISTIC = false
);
CREATE COLLATION


postgres=# SELECT 'ı' = 'I' COLLATE undefined_ci_nondet_old;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'i'='İ' COLLATE undefined_ci_nondet_old;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'i'='I' COLLATE undefined_ci_nondet_old;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'ı'='İ' COLLATE undefined_ci_nondet_old;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is a funny answer. At first I thought it was wrong because clearly switching to the `tr` locale cannot be the solution to be case-insensitive in *all* languages, right? But it turns out it is - the Turkish collation works not only for ı/I but also for example for ä/Ä (German), ø/Ø (Norwegian) and ж/Ж (Russian).

Comment: Could you maybe include those other characters in the example output, to make it immediately clear that the solution works not *only* for the dotless I?

Comment: @AndreKR: I've improved the answer a bit, including the 4 permutations of comparisons.

Comment: Oh, if `'i'='I'` is false, then the collation does not fulfill the purpose of `utf8_general_ci`.